# Is Zabbix network discoverer 1 threaded per discovery rule or across all discovery rules?

Tags: zabbix

I have set up two network discovery rules networks to test if they will be scanned simultaneously. Both the logged output of the discoverer thread (`zabbix_server --runtime-control log_level_increase=discoverer`) and the output of `tcpdump` shows me that each of those networks is scanned sequentially. This is not good because I have tons of /24 networks and I need them scanned independently.

Is there a way to mitigate this somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/discovery/network_discovery):

> Zabbix periodically scans the IP ranges defined in network discovery
>   rules. The frequency of the check is configurable for each rule
>   individually.
>
> Note that one discovery rule will always be processed by a single
>   discoverer process. The IP range will not be split between multiple
>   discoverer processes.

You should reconfigure the number of discovery processes (`StartDiscoverers`) in your `zabbix_server.conf` from 1, which is the default, to a higher value.

The right value depends on how many C class you need to scan, the frequerncy of the scan and the response speed of the scan itself.